# visual studios cout << not working

Tags: c++, cout

I am currently trying to learn the basics of C++. I am using visual studios and have found a strange problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string name = "Example name";
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;

    int pause;
    cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```

I cant use the "<<" twice when trying to output my string. It showes the red lines under the second << and wont let me compile. Any answers? Should I just use another IDE?

Comment: Add `#include <string>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to `#include <string>` where `operator<<` is defined for `std::string`

Comment: Oh, ok. The tutorial I was watching didn't mention that. Thank you! :-)